# Bash and SSH connection hangs after stopping tcpdump on ssh interface

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, tcpdump

My `SSH` connection hangs for ever if i stop `tcpdump` using `ctl c` or using linux `timeout` command. The `tcpdump` is being done on the `ssh` interface.

```
timeout 10 tcpdump -i eth0
```

In other words when using any stop signal eg. `SIGINT`, `SIGKILL` and `SIGTERM` on `tcpdump` on the ssh interface, my ssh connection hangs forever and it never comes back, and then i can't access the `server` again.

`server` = the server i access with ssh and has tcpdump installed,  "BareMetal server".

The only way it comes back is by restarting the server (restarting using IPMI server since i can't access the server via ssh).

What could be the problem?

Comment: "and then I can't access the host. the only way it comes back is by restarting the host" -- So "host" is the OS you access, i.e. the SSH server, right? If you need to restart the server, then I guess `tcpdump` was on the server. I'm not sure though. Please [edit] and clearly state what (e.g. `tcpdump`) is done where (the client or the server).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski the host = the server i access with ssh and has tcpdump installed "BareMetal server"

Comment: Do you have _console_ access via IPMI? Can you check `dmesg` at the time you stop tcpdump?

Comment: I checked the dmesg, and seems like when tcpdump is working, the interface enters the promiscuous mode and when it finishes it leaves the promiscuous mode, and there where the freeze happens.
so to pinpoint the problem, can't access the ssh interface when it leaves the promiscuous mode

Comment: Do you run `tcpdump` within a shell, or directly in SSH like `ssh login@example.com tcpdump ...`?
Also, does it happen with `tcpdump -i lo`? And does it also happen when enabling promiscuous mode manually with `ip link set eth0 promisc on/off`?

Comment: yes, as i mentioned in the previous comment, we can look at the problem now as a freeze when putting the interface promic mode off, 
to be more clear:
`ip link set eth0 promisc on` -- works normal
`ip link set eth0 promisc off` -- it go off the promisc mode(as i saw in dmesg) then the freeze happens immediately

Comment: Is the interface `eth0` a virtual interface, or a hardware interface? If it's a hardware interface, which driver, which version, which firmware version? (Guess: there's a bug in the driver/firmware when the interface leave promiscuous mode, but that shouldn't happen for a virtual interface).

Comment: @dirkt its a physical interface, i used eth0 for simplicity, its actual name is ens1f0

Comment: So please edit your question and add information about driver/firmware etc., because the next step is to google for this driver/firmware to see if others had the same problem, and if it's potentially already fixed, so you just need to upgrade the driver/firmware.

Answer (score 0):

The double ampersand or "&&" executes a following command once the preceding one finishes successfully. So I would try writing a restart for sshd after tcpdump is done to reset the ssh interface.

[Example:]

```
tcpdump -i eth0 && sudo systemctl restart sshd
```

Comment: that would kill other ssh traffic that also working on the server which is bad

Comment: oh s*%t  thank you for the correction